# Diagnostic.Process merge StandardOutput and StandardErrorOutput

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running cmd.exe from a .NET program using Process class and passing in various commands to execute programs i.e. ipconfig, netstat etc. The issue is that sometimes these programs output Error text, which is sent to StandardError, but there is no way of knowing where exactly during the Standard output the error actually was printed. All I get is the error message separately. Is it possible to combine StandardOutput and StandardError into one synchronized stream so that I get all data in order? If not, then how do I organize output from two different streams so that it's in proper order?

Comment: To merge streams you need: split data by messages, get it incoming number. Then you able to combine messages in one collection

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand? It's a stream, so as such there aren't any "messages" or "number" associated with any data.

Comment: streams are buffered, so you need to parse incoming parts of data. If you could't parse your output you could't correctly merge.

Comment: It is easy to do, you can ask cmd.exe to merge the two.  Append the cryptic `" 2>&1"` to its command line arguments.  Now all output goes to stdout and you can't tell the difference between normal and error output anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant What you suggested is what I'm looking for, however, it didn't work? I used 'p.StartInfo.Arguments = "2>&1"' in my code and stopped reading from StandardError stream. After I ran the code, I didn't get any error output at all.

Comment: You are not asking it to do anything, it will immediately exit.  *Append* that string to the Arguments.

Comment: @HansPassant I see what you are saying. The problem is that then all commands will have 2>&1 appended. So if a user types in ipconfig then the command in the output looks like "ipconfig 2>&1". This won't really work for me, as I'm looking for a cleaner solution. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Well. I guess you can't really expect that the STDOUT and STDERR come in the exact order they have been output. This is because at the system level, STDOUT and STDERR have their own buffer respectively. You can imagine such case -

(1) When the 'command' writes to STDOUT first, the buffer might not be flushed immediately.

(2) Then the 'command' writes to STDERR, however, this time the buffer for STDERR might get flushed.

In this case, even though (1) comes first, but what we get eventually is (2) comes first.

Hope the following snippet could help -

**(improved code)**

```
    class OutputContext
    {
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;

        public bool IsEof { get; set; }
        public bool IsWaiting { get; set; }
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        public StreamReader Reader { get; set; }
        public object Tag { get; set; }

        public OutputContext(StreamReader r, object tag)
        {
            IsEof = false;
            IsWaiting = false;
            Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            Reader = r;
            Tag = tag;
        }
    }

    Process proc;

    void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        lock (ar.AsyncState)
        {
            OutputContext ctx = ar.AsyncState as OutputContext;
            int c = ctx.Reader.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
            ctx.IsWaiting = false;

            if (c == 0)
            {
                ctx.IsEof = true;
                return;
            }

            string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ctx.Buffer, 0, c);
            Console.Write(content);
            Console.Out.Flush();

        }
    }

    void RedirectOutput(OutputContext ctx)
    {
        lock (ctx)
        {
            if (ctx.IsEof)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (ctx.IsWaiting)
            {
                return;
            }

            ctx.IsWaiting = true;
            IAsyncResult ar = ctx.Reader.BaseStream.BeginRead(ctx.Buffer, 0, 
                OutputContext.BufferSize, Callback, ctx);
        }
    }

    void Run(string yourprog, string yourargs)
    {
        // If this is a GUI app, this shall not be run on the UI thread.
        // Spin a new thread to handle it and wait for the thread to complete.
        // And you can always accept the input as long as the UI thread is not
        // blocked, and redirect the input to the target proc's stdin asycly.

        proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = yourprog;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = yourargs;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        proc.Start();

        OutputContext stdoutCtx = new OutputContext(proc.StandardOutput, "STDOUT");
        OutputContext stderrCtx = new OutputContext(proc.StandardError, "STDERR");

        while (!stdoutCtx.IsEof && !stderrCtx.IsEof)
        {
            RedirectOutput(stdoutCtx);
            RedirectOutput(stderrCtx);
        }

        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with using BeginOutputReadLine is that it doesn't output any prompts expecting an input...because there is no carriage return\line feed in it. It's only after you provide some input and hit Enter, is when the prompt will show up. That's why I had to move away from this approach.

Comment: @tunafish24 Is there any user interaction with console required? If that's the case, it becomes a little bit tricky... Since there're really 2 buffers for stdout and stderr, you don't know whether a character in stdout buffer comes earlier than the other in stderr buffer, and vice versa. AFAIK, the buffer is flushed automatically when it sees a linefeed. Otherwise, imperative flush is needed. In your case, when there's a prompt, there's no linefeed and the 'command' program is not done yet, so the prompt won't be flushed out to console. Let me think about it and get it back to you later.

Comment: They only have separate buffers if they are redirected to separate pipes.  Winapi makes it easy to specify the same pipe handle for both; .NET BCL does not.